# Copy a directory from multiple remote servers to localhost via ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I am trying to fetch a directory from multiple Linux hosts to a localhost via a bash script. But the `hostname` command shows the output of localhost instead of the remote host. The directory structure is : /home/user/HOSTNAME-BCKP on all the servers.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat hosts);
do
scp -r $i:/home/user/`hostname`-BCKP/home/user/ALL-BCKPs/;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `hostname`-command to show the **remote** hostname, you need to run it on the remote host.

You could read them into an associative array and loop over that:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -

declare -A myhosts
for item in $(cat hosts); do
  myhosts[$item]="$(ssh $item 'hostname')"
done

for key in "{!myhosts[@]}" ; do
  scp -r $key:/home/user/${myhosts[$key]}-BCKP /home/user/ALL-BCKPs/
done
```

But if you want to do this more than once, consider creating a file with a pair of host and hostname per line.

You can read that in a while-loop:

```bash
while read -r myhost myhostname; do
  # do something with $myhost and $myhostname
done < yourfile
```